# Euler product over subsets of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, euler-product

It is well known that
$$\prod_p\,(1-p^{-1})=\frac 1 {\zeta(1)}=0$$

> **Given an arbitrary prime $\,q\,$ is it true that**
>   $$\prod_{q\,|\,p+1}\,(1-p^{-1})=0\;\;\;?$$

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this follows from Dirichlet's theorem that for any $a$ and $q$ with $(a,q)=1$ the sum $\sum_{p\equiv a\pmod{q}}\frac{1}{p}$ diverges.

Comment: @ThomasBloom It doesn't quite follow from Dirichlet's Theorem, which usually merely states the infinitude of primes $a\pmod q$. Rather, the divergence of this sum of reciprocals happens to be the very result which is established in Dirichlet's proof, so his theorem follows from that. Alternatively we can deduce it from any of the various density results extending Dirichlet's Theorem.

Comment: @Wojowu: it'd be instructional to detail your reply in the "answer box".